# Input integer accumulating in loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, input

Im trying to create a loop where the loop's limit is pulled out from the input **"Enter # of Circles"**. It is currently accumulating values based on changes in the input.

Is there any way to just pull **only** the last value from the input to create a loop of divs?

Thanks Alot!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
       <title>Intro Webpage!</title>
       <style>
          div {
          width: 120px;
          height: 120px;
          display: inline-block;
          margin-left: 1px;
          }
       </style>
       <meta charset="UTF-8" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0; target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">     </script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <br>
       <b>Enter # of Circles<b>
       <br>
       <input type="integer" id="circles">   
       </b></b>
       <form>
          <div id="Participentfieldwrap">
             <svg height="100" width="200">
                <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100000000" y2="10000" style="stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5" />
                <svg height="100" width="100">
                   <circle id="cir" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
                </svg>
             </svg>
             <br>
             <b>Color<b>
             <br>
             <input type="integer" id="Color">
             </b></b>
             <script>
                //Inputing integer 1, 2 or 3 which instantly applies color formatting (RGB) to circle in the same div
                var cir = document.getElementById("cir");
                var into = document.getElementById("Color");
                into.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction, false);
                
                function myFunction() {
                    if(document.getElementById("Color").value == 1)
                        cir.style.fill = "green";
                    else if(document.getElementById("Color").value == 2)
                        cir.style.fill = "red";
                    else if(document.getElementById("Color").value == 3)
                        cir.style.fill = "blue";
                    else cir.style.fill = "Yellow";
                }
             </script>
          </div>
       </form>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          //Loop for creating multiple divs in a form using a limit that is set in an integer input
          var participantsField = document.getElementById("Participentfieldwrap"),
              form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0],
              ContestantNum = document.getElementById("circles"),
              i, timer;
          
          function createCircles(val) {
              for(i = 0; i < val; i++) {
                  var clone = participantsField.cloneNode(true);
                  form.appendChild(clone);
              }
          }
          ContestantNum.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
              if(timer) {
                  clearTimeout(timer);
              }
              timer = setTimeout(function() {
                  createCircles(ContestantNum.value);
              }, 800);
          });
       </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by last value of the input? Can you give some examples?

Comment: the last value that is typed in the Enter # of Circles input box.
So lets say you enter 5, it creates 5 extra circles, and if then overwrite the number 5 with 3, it would replace the 5 with 3.

If that wasnt clear, please do inform me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are appending to the existing circles, you are not clearing and removing the ones that exist when you create more. So it's appending more to what exist. What you need to do is remove the items (in this case being the children in `form`) before creating them from the input:

**Edit**

As *@Azamantes* pointed out there are duplicate id's for: `#Participentfieldwrap`, `#Color`, and `#cir`. I've updated the code so it assigns new id's being `Participentfieldwrap_i`, `Color_i`, and `cir_i`, where `i` goes from `0..n-1` per circle.

```
function createCircles(val) {
  // Removing previous circles
  while (form.firstChild) {
      form.removeChild(form.firstChild);
  }
  for(i = 0; i < val; i++) {
      var clone = participantsField.cloneNode(true);
      // Assigning new ids
      clone.id = "Participentfieldwrap_" + i;
      clone.querySelector("input").id = "Color_" + i;
      clone.querySelector("circle").id = "cir_" + i;
      form.appendChild(clone);
  }
  ...
```

Here is a Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
       <title>Intro Webpage!</title>
       <style>
          div {
          width: 120px;
          height: 120px;
          display: inline-block;
          margin-left: 1px;
          }
       </style>
       <meta charset="UTF-8" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0; target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">     </script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <br>
       <b>Enter # of Circles<b>
       <br>
       <input type="integer" id="circles">   
       </b></b>
       <form>
          <div id="Participentfieldwrap">
             <svg height="100" width="200">
                <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100000000" y2="10000" style="stroke:rgb(0,255,0);stroke-width:5" />
                <svg height="100" width="100">
                   <circle id="cir" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
                </svg>
             </svg>
             <br>
             <b>Color<b>
             <br>
             <input type="integer" id="Color">
             </b></b>
             <script>
                //Inputing integer 1, 2 or 3 which instantly applies color formatting (RGB) to circle in the same div
                var cir = document.getElementById("cir");
                var into = document.getElementById("Color");
                into.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction, false);
                
                function myFunction() {
                    if(document.getElementById("Color").value == 1)
                        cir.style.fill = "green";
                    else if(document.getElementById("Color").value == 2)
                        cir.style.fill = "red";
                    else if(document.getElementById("Color").value == 3)
                        cir.style.fill = "blue";
                    else cir.style.fill = "Yellow";
                }
             </script>
          </div>
       </form>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          //Loop for creating multiple divs in a form using a limit that is set in an integer input
          var participantsField = document.getElementById("Participentfieldwrap"),
              form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0],
              ContestantNum = document.getElementById("circles"),
              i, timer;
          
          function createCircles(val) {
              // Removing previous circles
              while (form.firstChild) {
                  form.removeChild(form.firstChild);
              }
              for(i = 0; i < val; i++) {
                  var clone = participantsField.cloneNode(true);
                  clone.id = "Participentfieldwrap_" + i;
                  clone.querySelector("input").id = "Color_" + i;
                  clone.querySelector("circle").id = "cir_" + i;
                  form.appendChild(clone);
              }
          }
          ContestantNum.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
              if(timer) {
                  clearTimeout(timer);
              }
              timer = setTimeout(function() {
                  createCircles(ContestantNum.value);
              }, 800);
          });
       </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!. I have been trying to get it working but the object IDs arn't being pulled out from the div ID.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are creating *many* circles with the same *ID*. ID in HTML is to be *unique* on the whole page. If you create many circles with the same `cir` id then when you do

```
document.getElementById('cir');
```

You're gonna get only 1 element with id `cir` (you can see the `elemenT` instead of `elemenTS` in the method name).

Same thing about `color` ID, you create more than 1 of them. Use `class` keyword instead and then instead of

```
document.getElementByID()
```

use something like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Color');
```

You can give them ids like `cir1`, `cir2` etc and `color1`, `color2` correspondingly and then get them number from input ID and find a circle with the same number.

Comment: That is definite! 

Do you know how to apply it under the scrip that is provided by Spencer Wieczorek?

Comment: @Dabbous I've updated my answer to account for that, thanks for mentioning that Azamantes.